# Why is my Function being called infinitely?

Tags: python, function

```
i = 1
while i != 3:
  if i == 1:
    def main3():
      decision3 = str(input("Do you accept? (Yes or No)"))
      if decision3 == 'No':
          print("narration")
      elif decision3 == 'Yes':
          print("narration")
          i = 2
      else:
          print("Sorry, that is an invalid input. Please re-enter.")
          main3()
    main3()
  else:
      i = 3
      print("narration")
```

It's supposed to run the code, and if the inout for decision three isn't Yes or No, the user is supposed to re-enter the input. Whenever I run the code, it infinitely asks decision3.

Comment: `i = 2` is being set in a different *scope*, it doesn't change the value you're checking outside `main3`.

Comment: Why are you redefining your function over and over and over and over and over and over and over .... again?

Comment: you can add ***global i*** to main3()

Comment: @itay that is a really bad solution to fix this convoluted code.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that question? It's a duplicate of any question regarding scoping, the issue has nothing to do with `input()`

Comment: @PatrickArtner, just for the sake of understanding scopes :)

Comment: @alec_a One duplicate solves the problem he wants to solve - the other 4 should explain the scoping problem at hand in enough detail so he can understand and fix it.

Comment: The others were added after I commented

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 3):

The value of `i` never changes, so `main3()` is perpetually called.

```
if i == 1:
    def main3():
      decision3 = str(input("Do you accept? (Yes or No)"))
      if decision3 == 'No':
          print("narration")
      elif decision3 == 'Yes':
          print("narration")
          i = 2  # <-- This does nothing to i outside of main3()!
      else:
          print("Sorry, that is an invalid input. Please re-enter.")
          main3()
    main3()  # <-- This is the problem!
```

`i` is only changed within the scope of `main3()`, not globally.

As a side note, don't cast the return of `input()` as a string. It already is one.